# Overflow Hidden Won't Text Wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image which is floated left and a div that has the following requirements : 
a)Needs max-height
b)Needs overflow: hidden . 
c)It's text needs to wrap around the floated image , just like in any normal float .

However I am having a problem with (C) , the text isn't wrapping . I've read that overflow:hidden actually prevents the text from wrapping .

Does anyone know any solution (preferably css) for this ?

As you can see the text isn't wrapping around the cat image : 
**http://jsfiddle.net/FWjG4/**

```
<html>
   <style>
     #articleContainer {
     width: 500px;
     height: 800px;
     color: pink;
        }

    .photo {
     float: left;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
         }

    .article {
       max-height: 300px;
       max-width: 200px;
       overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>
    <body>
     <div id="articleContainer">
        <img class="photo" src="googleyosemite.jpg" />
        <div class="article" >blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah bla
         </div>

             </div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

put the image inside the article div.

http://jsfiddle.net/FWjG4/3/

```
<div class="article" >
<img class="photo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9gFNtL3J-Qz7phuIK4F98X3UcRqAhihW4bdF70Ka07MzF-3yfjQ" /><p>blah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blahblah blah blah</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No update on CSS, just place your image inside the div.

```
   <div id="articleContainer">

            <div class="article" ><img class="photo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9gFNtL3J-Qz7phuIK4F98X3UcRqAhihW4bdF70Ka07MzF-3yfjQ" />blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah




            </div>

   </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/shekhardesigner/dKjwz/

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWjG4/4/)

**`HTML`**

```
<body>
    <div id="articleContainer">
        <img class="photo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS9gFNtL3J-Qz7phuIK4F98X3UcRqAhihW4bdF70Ka07MzF-3yfjQ" />
        <div class="article" >blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blahblah blah blahblah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah
            blah blah blah




        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

**`CSS`**

```
#articleContainer {
     width: 200px; /* width is reduced*/
     height: 800px;
     color: pink;
}

.photo {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.article {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try css{    white-space: pre-line; }